# DataGridView bound to EF collection not updating

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview

There are a ton of postings on related topics but I can't figure out what in the world is going on. I have a winform app containing a datagrid that displays the contents of a SQL table (a list of accounts). I'm using the the entity framework model for data management.

Intended functionality is as follows. When the main form launches, it creates an instance of the data model called "ODS." The data is then linked to the datagrid via the following call in the form's load() method:

```
grid_accounts.DataSource = ODS.Accounts;
```

When an "add account" button is clicked on the main form, it opens a dialog for the user to fill in the new account info. The data source is passed to the dialog. If the user clicks OK, the new account entity is created, added to ODS.Accounts, saved, and the dialog closed. The datagrid on the main form should then show the new account.

All of this happens as intended EXCEPT the new account doesn't appear in the datagrid. I've checked, and it IS saved to the database once SaveChanges() is called. I've also outputted the contents of ODS.Accounts to the console and the new entity is indeed in the collection. I've tried calling Refresh() on the datagrid; I've also tried the well-known trick of setting the grid's dataSource to null prior to resetting it to the Account collection to "fool" the grid into updating. No luck. Am I missing something obvious? Relevant code below. Thanks.

The MainForm:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    VHN.DataAccess.ODSEntities ODS = VHN.DataAccess.Util.getODS();

    private void Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        populate();
    }

    private void button_addAccount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var d = new NewAccountForm(ODS);
        if (d.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            populate();
    }

    void populate()
    {
        grid_accounts.DataSource = null;
        grid_accounts.DataSource = ODS.Accounts;

        grid_accounts.Columns[0].Visible = false;
        grid_accounts.Refresh();            
    }
}
```

The new account dialog:

```
public partial class NewAccountForm : Form
{
    VHN.DataAccess.ODSEntities ODS;

    public NewAccountForm(ref VHN.DataAccess.ODSEntities ODS)
    {
        this.ODS = ODS;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ok_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int count = ODS.Accounts.Where(x => x.name == tb_name.Text).Count();

        if (count > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Account name \"'{0}\" is already taken.", tb_name.Text));
        }
        else
        {
            VHN.DataAccess.Account account = new VHN.DataAccess.Account();
            account.id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            account.name = tb_name.Text;
            ODS.Accounts.AddObject(account);
            ODS.SaveChanges();
            this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
            Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try one of these: (Assuming Accounts is a List type

```
grid_accounts.EndEdit();
grid_accounts.Refresh();
```

OR

```
grid_accounts.DataSource = typeof(List); 
grid_accounts.DataSource = ODS.Accounts;
```

Update:

```
grid_accounts.DataSource = typeof(List<>); // OR use grid_accounts.DataSource = null;
grid_accounts.DataSource = ODS.Accounts.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried both - neither worked. Accounts is an ObjectSet<Account> type.

Comment: Can I ask how are you fetching the data in getODS() method?

Comment: It just returns an instance of the data model:return new ODSEntities(connectionString);

Comment: Try returning the ODS instance as an Enumerable().

Comment: See edit. I have created a dummy project and used this and it does refresh the datagridview.

Comment: Right. First of all glad to be of help. Secondly, Datasource of gridviewcontrol works on IEnumerable so it recognizes changes when either IEnumerable, ICollection, IList is passed to its data grid or its concrete implementations.

Answer (score 0):

if you are still on this.

```
grid_accounts.DataSource = new BindingSource(ODS.Accounts);
```

should work just fine.